# CSS appears different on Windows than Mac

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, nav

When I view the site in Windows then most of the site, like the top text, right contact details, nav text and welcome text appear lower than they do on the mac. Mac browsers show the CSS as it should be. Please help me out...

Mac screenshot

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwe9hxfkfie3xqu/Mac%20screenchot.png]

Windows screenshot

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9cnl3lczzrcmtp/Windows%20screenshot.png]

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wholepage">
<header>
<div id="nav_top">
<nav>
<h1 class="slogan">Steel & Fabrication Specialists</h1>
</nav>
</div>
<a href="index.html"><img class="kks_logo" src="KKSLogo.png" border="0" alt="KKS Services   Ltd logo"></a>
<h1 class="logo">KKS</h1>
<h2 class="logosub">Services Ltd</h2>
<h3 class="head_contact">0113 2826946</h3>
<h3 class="head_contact"><a href="contact.html">enquiries@kksservices.co.uk</a></h3>
<nav id="main_nav">
<ul id="nav_main">
 <li><a class="current_index" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a class="domestic" href="domestic.html">DOMESTIC</a></li>
 <li><a class="automation" href="automation.html">AUTOMATION</a></li>
 <li><a class="commercial" href="commercial.html">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
 <li><a class="contact" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<img class="rivot" src="rivot.png" alt="KKS Services Ltd Rivot"/>
<img class="rivot2" src="rivot.png" alt="KKS Services Ltd Rivot"/>
<img class="rivot3" src="rivot.png" alt="KKS Services Ltd Rivot"/>
<img class="rivot4" src="rivot.png" alt="KKS Services Ltd Rivot"/>
</header>
<section>
<article>
<img class="railings" src="index_rail.png" alt="KKS Services Gates and Railings"/>
 <div id="welcome">
<h1 class="welcome">Welcome</h1>
```

CSS

```
.slogan{
position: relative;
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 10px;
top: -5px;
color: white;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-family: 'Aldrich', cursive;
}
.kks_logo{
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}
.head_contact{
font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: -175px;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: right;
}
ul#nav_main li{
display: inline;
padding: 26px;
}
ul#nav_main li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.4em;
position: relative;
top: 13px;
}
#welcome{
position: relative;
top: -267px;
left: 70px;
width: 840px;
height: 35px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
border-radius: 5px;
}
#welcome h1{
color: white;
font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 200%;
position: relative;
top: -5px;
left: 10px;
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use absolute and/or relative positioning for everything... In order to fix it you'll need to either re-structure your CSS (recommended) or use media queries and/or Javascript to compensate.

Comment: Okay, in terms of restructuring the CSS code what would you recommend the best thing to use instead of relative and absolute positions?

Comment: Are you resetting the default browser rules? What browsers were you using on each system?

Comment: @DrydenLong I'd have to say that was the worst set of advice I've **ever** seen here on SO...

Comment: @Shomz Why is that? I'll admit it wasn't the most *constructive* of advice, but it is a valid reason not to use relative positioning on every element.

Comment: @Shomz thank you for your input, I'm quite new on here so appreciate the help! By resetting the browser rules is that when you set pretty much all the tags to like margin: 0; etc... and would i need to set font-size: 100%; to that which may sort it out?

Comment: @DrydenLong The relative part was fine... But, restructure CSS - no! Use media queries for this - NO! Use JS - GOD NO!! Sorry if I sounded too harsh, but it was an impulse.

Comment: @kwright2713 Yes, margins, paddings, borders, outlines (for form fields and buttons). Basically, you can see those differences on a single system using a couple of different browsers (Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, Safari, nothing too fancy, and usually 2 or 3 are enough). You also have those ready CSS reset sheets that you load before your own ones (like the answer here suggests). You'll get the hang of which rules are troublesome in time, don't worry. :)

Comment: @Shomz No need to apologize, it's the internet so I take everything with a grain of salt :) That makes sense, I guess I did go a little over-the-top with my JS/media queries suggestion. I still think restructuring the CSS to not rely on relative positioning is a good thing though.

Comment: @DrydenLong That's the approach. Anyway, it's the unaddressed default browser rules are what is killing the layout here... and a little bit of different rendering on each (which is fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the different default styles that browsers have. Neither way of displaying your page is wrong, they are just different.

You have compensated for the default styles of one browser, which makes it look quite different in all other browsers. As long as you compensate for the default styles instead of overriding them, you will have that problem.

For example, for the `.slogan` style you should set the top and bottom margin to zero, instead of using relative positioning to compensate for the default margin. You can use `line-height` to center the text vertically in the element, instead of moving it up or down to place it in the center.

Example:

```
.slogan{
  width: 960px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: 'Aldrich', cursive;
}
```

Comment: That's great thank you for your example here. After tinkering with my CSS, removing some of the relative positioning and using line-height has got it pretty much perfect on both OS'.

Comment: Guffa, I have same problem, but me and my friend use Chrome. But she has Linux and I have Windows. Does it matter even same browsers but different OS?

Comment: @UlviEnzo: Yes, there are many factors that affect how web pages are displayed, so there may be differences even if you have the same browser and the same OS. Other factors include browser version, screen resolution, OS font rendering settings, OS font scaling settings, screen calibration, browser zoom, to mention some of the most common. To make web pages appear identical in all cases is impossible, you just have to find the solutions where the differences have minimal effect.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought I'd offer another answer... A solution I've used is to detect the OS using js, and set a class on the body denoting the OS.

```
//Windows
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add("win");  
}
//Mac
else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add("mac");
}
```

Then in your css you can make special rules for the specific scenarios you need:

```
.some-class-name{
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.mac .some-class-name{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Different browsers have different CSS presets, or defaults.  Therefore the default rendering will vary.  In order to get around this problem, you can use a CSS reset stylesheet.  Here is one that works well:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Using a reset stylesheet will remove any browser defaults.  You can then add in your own margin/padding styling.  This may require some adjustments to your current CSS values, but it will help overall when making your CSS cross-browser compatible.

Comment: +1 But it might be worth mentioning that sometimes those reset CSS are an overkill and, if possible and applicable, you shouldn't hesitate writing your own.

Comment: +1 Absolutely. 'Generic' reset stylesheets will attempt to cover almost every applicable markup tag.  You may find it more suitable to reset just the tags that you are using.