# Padding looks different on Mac than on Windows

Tags: html, css, wordpress, padding, styling

For some reason, the padding appears different on all windows computers. My icons aren't located properly in the middle nor is the text in my buttons. It is working perfectly on windows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/syazk.jpg - here is an example picture

See more at: https://cobury.dk/

The CSS/HTML I use:

```html
i.icon-facebook, i.icon-instagram, i.icon-linkedin, i.icon-youtube {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 99px;
    background: #19191b;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

<div class="somefooter2"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/cobury" target="_blank" rel="noopener">[icon type="icon-facebook"]</a><a href="https://www.instagram.com/coburyagency/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">[icon type="icon-instagram"]</a><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cobury/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">[icon type="icon-linkedin"]</a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6qwqVJl6ZodTBZraamdLLg" target="_blank" rel="noopener">[icon type="icon-youtube"]</a></div>
```

The padding is perfect in Chrome on Windows, but looks weird on both Chrome/Safari on Mac. I am using the same padding top and bottom, as you can see. What am I missing? Is it something about my divs? Line height? A bug?

I am using the paid font Gilroy.

Comment: Post your HTML to the question. If you fix that link, this question will be useless to future visitors. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please include your HTML in addition to your CSS. This is still not a minimal reproducible example. Does this answer your question? [CSS appears different on Windows than Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700119/css-appears-different-on-windows-than-mac)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have tried to edit my post with the html used on the icons.

Comment: Combine those snippets...move your CSS to the HTML one.

Comment: Done :) Thank you.

Comment: disinfor, whould you mind to explain how did you fix it? Today I suddenly found that when my friend runs my code in her computer, icons inside div appears differently as yours. How to solve it for all devices?